# Android Retrofit - onProgressUpdate for showing Progress Notification

Tags: android, android-asynctask, retrofit

I'm currently using Retrofit by Square for Android network communications. Is there a way to get its progress during a task to create a progress notification, something similar to that which Facebook uses when uploading an image?

Use Case would be to load an image hopefully of full image quality without compression or scaling.

I see how it is possible with an asynctask but that would defeat the purpose of using Retrofit. However that might be the route I would have to take.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the use case? Most simple Retrofit requests are so short as to not need progress indicators, but I'm guessing you're using PUT or POST to upload a file like a picture?

Comment: Precisely @Hober, would you recommend against not using retrofit to upload a picture? And if so, do you have any recommendations?

Comment: I implemented this a while ago but couldn't find the solution so I made an indeterminate progress bar instead.

Comment: @NujnaH to be precise did you mean you implemented sending a picture with retrofit, and just created an indeterminate progress bar, then during the Success would just finish it? (Thats basically what I am doing now as well)

Comment: Yep! That's exactly what I ended up doing

Comment: but the question is very valid. Is it possible to show progress in Retrofit while uploading heavy data? Indeterminate Progress bar is a workaround.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

**This answer is for Retrofit 1. For solution compatible with Retrofit 2 [see  this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33384551/1235698).**

---

I had the same problem and finally managed to do it. I was using spring lib before and what I show below kind worked for Spring but was inconsistent since I made a mistake on using it for the InputStream. I moved all my API's to use retrofit and upload was the last one on the list, I just override **TypedFile** writeTo() to update me on the bytes read to the OutputStream. Maybe this can be improved but as I said I made it when I was using Spring so I just reused it.
This is the code for upload and it's working for me on my app, if you want download feedback then you can use @Streaming and read the inputStream.

**ProgressListener**

```
public interface ProgressListener {
 void transferred(long num);
}
```

**CountingTypedFile**

```
public class CountingTypedFile extends TypedFile {

 private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

 private final ProgressListener listener;

 public CountingTypedFile(String mimeType, File file, ProgressListener listener) {
    super(mimeType, file);
    this.listener = listener;
 }

 @Override public void writeTo(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(super.file());
    long total = 0;
    try {
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            total += read;
            this.listener.transferred(total);
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
 }
}
```

**MyApiService**

```
public interface MyApiService {
 @Multipart
 @POST("/files")
 ApiResult uploadFile(@Part("file") TypedFile resource, @Query("path") String path);
}
```

**SendFileTask**

```
private class SendFileTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ApiResult> {
    private ProgressListener listener;
    private String filePath;
    private FileType fileType;

    public SendFileTask(String filePath, FileType fileType) {
        this.filePath = filePath;
        this.fileType = fileType;
    }

    @Override
    protected ApiResult doInBackground(String... params) {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        totalSize = file.length();
        Logger.d("Upload FileSize[%d]", totalSize);
        listener = new ProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void transferred(long num) {
                publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
            }
        };
        String _fileType = FileType.VIDEO.equals(fileType) ? "video/mp4" : (FileType.IMAGE.equals(fileType) ? "image/jpeg" : "*/*");
        return MyRestAdapter.getService().uploadFile(new CountingTypedFile(_fileType, file, listener), "/Mobile Uploads");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        Logger.d(String.format("progress[%d]", values[0]));
        //do something with values[0], its the percentage so you can easily do
        //progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
    }
}
```

The **CountingTypedFile** is just a copy of **TypedFile** but including the ProgressListener.

Comment: YOU. ARE. KING. This is great work, Davi. Especially with little to no documentation around this. Btw, I renamed `CountingTypedFile` to `TypedFileWithProgressListener`.

Comment: I'm glad I could help man! When possible try to migrate to retrofit 2.x, they have improved and this is part of the framework now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the max value in order to show it on a ProgressDialog, Notification, etc.

**ProgressListener**

```
public interface ProgressListener {
    void transferred(long num, long max);
}
```

**CountingTypedFile**

```
public class CountingTypedFile extends TypedFile {

    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

    private final ProgressListener listener;

    public CountingTypedFile(String mimeType, File file, ProgressListener listener) {
        super(mimeType, file);
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(super.file());
        long total = 0;
        try {
            int read;
            while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                total += read;
                this.listener.transferred(total, super.file().length());
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
    }
}
```