# Is it possible to show progress bar when download file via Retrofit 2, Android

Tags: android, download, retrofit

I'am currently using Retrofit 2 and i want to download some file from my server.
Can i call back some event to catch percent complete download file to show in notification like this picture [image]

I reference that link, but it is upload, can i do it with same problem?
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338181/is-it-possible-to-show-progress-bar-when-upload-image-via-retrofit-2/33384551#33384551)

Is it possible to show progress when using retrofit 2 library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348812/android-retrofit-onprogressupdate-for-showing-progress-notification)

Comment: it is uploading image, can i do it with same ?

Comment: yes it is uploading file.

Comment: friend, i need download file.

Comment: @NguyễnHoàng could you past your code into your post to know after resolve your problem how can we approach to that?  Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `ResponseBody` and set it to `OkHttp` client and to update progress in UI you can use interface.[check this link](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/Progress.java)

Comment: Can you print some logs to verify if call is coming to ResponseBody.when you say its not working what does it mean

Comment: Yes, I know that is java code, so i change System.out.println to Log.i. And I i see this exception.
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName

Comment: NetworkOnMainThread is different exception which occurs when you doing heavy operation in UI like networking and other blocking calls.So move your code to background Thread

Comment: YES, you save my day :), tks so much

Comment: But. it not retrofit !! :), any idea >

Comment: If i am getting your question then, retrofit uses OkHttp client by default and you want to intercept response to show progress hence we are using ResponseBody.

Comment: can you explain it more detail

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could use an Intent service as described [here](https://www.journaldev.com/22494/android-retrofit-download-image-progress-notification).

I will show you how I used the above... The only difference is the portion where the file is written to disk.

Define the service:

```
public class BackgroundNotificationService extends IntentService {

    public BackgroundNotificationService() {
        super("Service");
    }

    private NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;

    private String mAgentsID;
    private String mReportsID;
    private String mJobID;
    private String mFileName;


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("id", "an", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);

            notificationChannel.setDescription("no sound");
            notificationChannel.setSound(null, null);
            notificationChannel.enableLights(false);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(false);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }


        notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "id")
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download)
                .setContentTitle("Download")
                .setContentText("Downloading Image")
                .setDefaults(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

        mAgentsID = intent.getStringExtra("AgentsID");
        mReportsID = intent.getStringExtra("ReportsID");
        mJobID = intent.getStringExtra("JobID");
        mFileName = intent.getStringExtra("FileName");

        initRetrofit();

    }

    private void initRetrofit(){
        Call<ResponseBody> downloadCall = ApiManager.getJasperReportsService().DownloadAgentReportData(mAgentsID, mReportsID, mJobID, mFileName);

        try {
            writeResponseBodyToDisk(downloadCall.execute().body(), mFileName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    private boolean writeResponseBodyToDisk(ResponseBody body, String FileName) {
        try {
            File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
            File DownloadedFile = new File(SDCardRoot + File.separator + FileName);

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            OutputStream outputStream = null;

            try {
                byte[] fileReader = new byte[4096];

                long fileSize = body.contentLength();
                long fileSizeDownloaded = 0;

                long total = 0;
                boolean downloadComplete = false;

                inputStream = body.byteStream();
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(DownloadedFile);

                while (true) {
                    int read = inputStream.read(fileReader);

                    if (read == -1) {
                        downloadComplete = true;
                        break;
                    }

                    total += read;
                    int progress = (int) ((double) (total * 100) / (double) fileSize);

                    updateNotification(progress);

                    outputStream.write(fileReader, 0, read);

                    fileSizeDownloaded += read;


                    Log.d("DOWNLOAD FILE", "file download: " + fileSizeDownloaded + " of " + fileSize);
                }
                onDownloadComplete(downloadComplete);

                outputStream.flush();

                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return false;
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }

                if (outputStream != null) {
                    outputStream.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void updateNotification(int currentProgress) {


        notificationBuilder.setProgress(100, currentProgress, false);
        notificationBuilder.setContentText("Downloaded: " + currentProgress + "%");
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }


    private void sendProgressUpdate(boolean downloadComplete) {

        Intent intent = new Intent("progress_update");
        intent.putExtra("downloadComplete", downloadComplete);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(BackgroundNotificationService.this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private void onDownloadComplete(boolean downloadComplete) {
        sendProgressUpdate(downloadComplete);

        notificationManager.cancel(0);
        notificationBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
        notificationBuilder.setContentText("Download Complete");
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        notificationManager.cancel(0);
    }

}
```

And then use the intent service:

```
private void registerReceiver() {

    LocalBroadcastManager bManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(itemView.getContext());
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("progress_update");
    bManager.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);

}

private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals("progress_update")) {

            boolean downloadComplete = intent.getBooleanExtra("downloadComplete", false);
            //Log.d("API123", download.getProgress() + " current progress");

            if (downloadComplete) {

                Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "File download completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    }
};

private void startDownload(String jobID, String FileName) {


    Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), BackgroundNotificationService.class);
    // TODO customze to suit your own needs.
    intent.putExtra("AgentsID", mAgentsID);
    intent.putExtra("ReportsID", mReportsID);
    intent.putExtra("JobID", jobID);
    intent.putExtra("FileName", FileName);
    itemView.getContext().startService(intent);

}
```

so you use `registerReceiver()` on start of your activity and then if you have a button to initiate the download, you in the onClick method run `startDownload()`. As an extra note, you can customize the intent variables(if you need any), to your needs.